'libjsoncpp24' dependency error when installing cmake
I have Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1 (debian version: 11.3, Linux raspberrypi 6.6.59-v8+):
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

The following command to install cmake
sudo apt-get install cmake

gives me the following error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: libjsoncpp24 (>= 1.9.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I tried to install libjsoncpp24 (sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp24). However, this gives another error:
Package libjsoncpp24 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libjsoncpp24' has no installation candidate

Does anyone have a solution to this? I couldn't find any resources to fix this issue.

You are running an old OS (Bullseye) but an unsupported 6.6.59 kernel (presumably with rpi-update despite the warnings).
If you choose to install testing software expect problems.
sudo apt update; sudo apt install --reinstall libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-{bin,dev,doc} raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.
